# WinForm/C# - Add data in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need some control which can change data row or can add new data row in a DataGridView.

You knwo we have two ways: one using the same row of the gridview and second to have some gridcontrol which when we click in the row of the grid expands the control to set data and save t to the grid. And in new data the same. Like in Telerik but using a free control.

Second case it is what I am looking for.

Could you please tell me the best control to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195423/DataGridViewExtension) is what you are looking for.